# Adding more results to the thesis

Tags: thesis, thesis-committee

Is it possible to add some additional results after submitting the "complete" thesis to advisor. I must add that my advisor has already sent the thesis to Ph.D commission.

The additional results are *not* a correction of the thesis. I just want to add some more results to it.

Comment: Publish the modified thesis as a separate book, if no formal publication is required for original thesis. Or just make a paper out of the new stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with your advisor, and if they do not know, check with your department director of graduate studies (it may have a different name, but it is a faculty member who is "in charge" of the PhD program).

In general, there shouldn't be any problem, but your institution may have special policies and what not. As always, it is better to be open about any changes. More communication is better that less.

Be positive when you write to your advisor and motivate the changes.. E.g., "I would like to add these results *because* they improve the dissertation in such and such a way ..."

Answer (score 0):

It depends strongly on the PhD-process in your institution. E.g. my "old" university required me to publish my thesis and I was able to change and add stuff during the process. But those changes were not revied by a comittee so they had no impact towards my grade.

The general rule at my current institution is, that you can not change your thesis (no matter if bachelor, master or PhD) after you submitted it. But you could add an addendum and maybe someone loooks at it ;-).